# Uni-Select (UNS.TO) Market Cap Incorrect?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, yahoo-finance

Looking at the Uni-Select stock listed on the Toronto Stock Exchange (UNS.TO), share price is $31.85. Shares outstanding is listed as 21,295,405 from the company's website (http://uniselect.com/en/investors/stock-information).

Market cap should be $31.85 * 21,295,405 = $678M.

However yahoo finance and google both lists market cap around $1.3B.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your link shows the shares as of March 31, 2016 while http://uniselect.com/content/files/Press-release/Press-Release-Q1-2016-Final.pdf notes a 2-for-1 stock split so thus you have to double the shares to get the proper number is what you are missing. The stock split occurred in May and thus is after the deadline that you quoted.

Comment: Wow, that is absolutely incredible then. It means the market only valued the company at ~$600 million late last year ($30/share 21 million shares), but if we take conservative net income after taxes of $38 million a year; calculate npv using discount rate of 3%; we would get market cap of $1.1 B! This stock was undervalued as hell! Or I guess investors weren't sure how to forecast forward earnings with the selling of their Uni-Select US business to Carl Icahn. I guess they assumed net earnings would be halved.